# Give formbuilder class value as 'hidden'

Tags: symfony

I would like to give formBuilder User Entity as hidden value.

```
$form->add('user','hidden',array("data" => $user))
```

$user is User Entity.

However it shows this error.

`Expected argument of type "Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", "string" given`

If I use 'null' instead of 'hidden'

```
$form->add('user',null,array("data" => $user))
```

it doesn't show the error and shows the select box of user Entity.

However I would like to use hidden.
How can I make it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did't specify the field type correctly - this is the correct way:

```
...
$formBuilder->add('user', HiddenType::class);
...
...
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();
$form->get('user')->setData($user->getId());
```

But you can't assign entity to the hidden field, so you can assign user's id for user identification.

Another option is to make data transformer and define own EntityHiddenType - more on this here: [symfony : can't we have a hidden entity field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094901/symfony-cant-we-have-a-hidden-entity-field)

Comment: I see , I understood. put Entity as hidden value is impossible. You give me the nice hint. thank you very much

Comment: Do you want to store UserId value from user input?
If not, use `$form->add('user',null,array("data" => $user, 'mapped' => false))`.